# SQL exception while selecting the columns with alias names

Tags: c#, alias, sqlexception

My SQL query is

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("select vchr_No as voucher No, vchr_Date as Date, 
                        vchr_Acnthd as Debit, vchr_Prtynm as Paid to 
                        from cshvchrs  
                        where vchr_No like '%" + vchno + "%' ", con);
```

When I try to retrieve the data I am getting an exception:

> *The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.*

Please anybody help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `vchr_Date as Date` part,

`Date` is a [`reserved keyword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) on Transact-SQL.

> Reserved keywords are part of the grammar of the Transact-SQL language
>   that is used by SQL Server to parse and understand Transact-SQL
>   statements and batches.

You can use it with square brackets `[]` like;

```
vchr_Date as [Date]
```

Use your full query as;

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("select vchr_No as [voucher No] ,vchr_Date as [Date] ,vchr_Acnthd as Debit ,vchr_Prtynm as Paid to from cshvchrs  where vchr_No like '%" + vchno + "%' ", con);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have invalid SQL - the aliases that contain spaces need to be escaped, as do aliases that are keywords.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("select vchr_No as [voucher No] ,vchr_Date as [Date] ,vchr_Acnthd as Debit ,vchr_Prtynm as Paid to from cshvchrs  where vchr_No like '%" + vchno + "%' ", con);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Date` as alias (`vchr_Date as Date`). `Date` is a reserved keyword, try:

```
vchr_Date as [Date]
```

or change `Date` to some other alias.

You also need to use `[]` around aliases with space.

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly specified column names . For instance, the fragment:

```
vchr_No as voucher No
```

should be expressed as

```
vchr_No as [voucher No]
```

or you will not have valid SQL.

In general, you need to put [ and ] around column names that contain spaces, punctuation, keywords, or any other characters that are not permitted in SQL column identifiers.